# Zend 2 Accessing different url from controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is there a way to access a url that is different to the controller name?

Say, for my real life example, that I want to access this url http://www.example.com/men with men being a category. My controller would be CategoryController and it would display information from a database that would be appropriate to whatever category had been selected.

The reason I need it like this is because I need to support multiple sites so I can't have a controller for each category. Is there a way to do this? I'm fairly new to the 2 Framework but have decent knowledge of 1.12. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestand you correctly, you may resolve your task by routing configuration.

Module's `module.config.php` file:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            '<ROUTE_NAME>' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/:category',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'category' => '<CATEGORY_PATTERN>', // usually [a-zA-Z0-9-_]+
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => '<CategoryController Namespace>',
                        'controller' => 'Category',
                        'action' => '<Controller method without "action" postfix>',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Inside controller category accessed by:

```
$category = $this->params()->fromRoute('category');
```